# Check my proof. Set Theory

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

If $ A\setminus B =B\setminus A $,

so $A=B$

Please look at my answer

Let $ x \in A\setminus B \Rightarrow (x \in A \land x \notin B) \land (x\notin A \land x \in B)  \Rightarrow x \in \emptyset \Rightarrow A=B   $

Is this way of thinking correct?

Comment: Some $\implies$ lost in the way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like an intuitive proof. For set theory, more formal proofs are expected.

You want to prove that $A=B$. The standard way to do this is assuming that some $x$ is in $A$ and prove that it is also in $B$, and also, the other way around. Since the statement that you want to proof is the same if you swap the letters $A$ and $B$, 'the other way around' is not needed now.

So take some $x\in A$. If $x\in B$ then there is nothing to prove. Otherwise (that is, if $x\notin B$), $x\in A\setminus B$ and then $x\in B\setminus A$, so $x\notin A$, a contradiction.  So there is no 'otherwise'; that is, $x\in B$.

Comment: Notice that $B-A$ and $A-B$ may be empty;did you consider that case?

Comment: Yes. Note that  "something that it is false" implies "anything that you can imagine, or can't".

Comment: Actually my comment was for the one who asked the question.

Answer (score 2):

$$
(x\in A\setminus B\implies x\in B\setminus A\implies (x\in A\land x\notin B) \land(x\notin A\land x\in B)\implies x\in\emptyset)\\\implies A\subset B.
$$
and by symmetry $B\subset A$.

Comment: I'm not wild about $x\in\emptyset$ used as notation for a contradiction, but aside from that this proof is a solid version of the OP's.

Comment: @MatthewDaly, I *wanted* a repaired version of the OP's proof.

Comment: @MatthewDaly So have You any idea, how I should write it correctly?

Comment: I get that.  I just wanted to upvote your solution and register my concern at the same time.

Comment: @Kukoz I'm not sure there is a symbolic way to do proofs by contradiction clearly. I think a sentence-based proof like ajotatxe would make for a clearer argument.

Answer (score 0):

Let's solve it in this way.
if $ A\setminus B =B\setminus A $,

so
$ A\setminus B = A - A \cap B \space $ and $\space B\setminus A = B - A \cap B $

so  $ A -A \cap B = B - A \cap B \Rightarrow A=B $